# How do you call a models function in ember.js from your template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

```
App.Post = Em.Object.extend({
    content: null
});

App.Post.reopenClass({
    getLink: function() {
      console.log("test");
    }.property('content')
});

----template clip----
            {{#each this}}
                {{getLink}}
                {{content}}
            {{/each}}
```

getLink isn't getting called in my template. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ember, `reopenClass` is used to create class methods or add properties to the class itself. So you have defined App.Post.getLink, but the template seems to be looking for a getLink property on instances of App.Post. Probably what you want instead is to use `reopen` which will add methods and properties to all instances of a class.

```
App.Post.reopen({
  getLink: function() {
    console.log("test");
  }.property('content')
});
```

See the [reopening classes and instances](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/) guide for more detail on how this all works.